# Proof that a limit can be brought into the integral

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence

I need to prove that 
$$
\lim\limits_{\large s \to \infty} \int \limits_{0_+}^\infty \left[ \dfrac{d x(t)}{dt} \right] e^{-\large st} dt = 0
$$

The problem is that I need to prove why I can bring the limit inside the integral for s a complex variable.

If someone can help me it would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know about the function $x$?

It may be helpful to note that this is the Laplace transform of $x'$, i.e.

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx(t)}{dt} e^{-st} dt = \mathcal{L}\left\{x' \right\}(s) = s\mathcal{L}\left\{x\right\}(s) - x(0).
$$

So, if you know some properties of the Laplace transform of $x$, then you can work with the limit directly. Otherwise, this demonstrates that this cannot hold for general $x$; e.g. if $x$ is the unit step function, then the limit is $1$.